# Python combine variable number of lists via identifiers

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I'm quite a newbie and I'm converting all my excel vba to python at this moment.

I have these lists.

```
s1a = [1, 2, 3]
s1b = [2, 3, 4]
s2a = [3, 4, 5]
s2b = [4, 5, 6]
s3a = [5, 6, 7]
s3b = [6, 7, 8]
```

and I've got another list,

```
result = ['s2as1a', 's1bs2a', 's1as3b', 's2as3a']
```

from the lists above, I'd like to make the following lists.

```
A = [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3] # s2a + s1a
B = [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5] # s1b + s2a
C = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8] # s1a + s3b
D = [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7] # s2a + s3a
```

I tried to make this but I can only come up with some messy "if/elif" things.

How to make this in a nice and simple way?
thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is not to do this.

Use a dictionary for a variable number of variables.

```
result = ['s2as1a', 's1bs2a', 's1as3b', 's2as3a']

d = {'s1a': [1, 2, 3], 's1b': [2, 3, 4],
     's2a': [3, 4, 5], 's2b': [4, 5, 6],
     's3a': [5, 6, 7], 's3b': [6, 7, 8]}

res = {idx: d[i[:3]] + d[i[-3:]] for idx, i in enumerate(result)}

{0: [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3],
 1: [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5],
 2: [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8],
 3: [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7]}
```